# MIPS Assembly Char Input

Tags: assembly, io, char, mips

I've encountered this problem, trying to get user's char input in MIPS Assembly.
I seem to not understand why, when inputting a char, pressing ENTER is not required, whilst when inputting any other type, such as .word, you always have to press ENTER. Could you please explain it to me and tell me what I did wrong in the code? Thank you.

Here is the code in question:

```
.data
message:  .asciiz "Please, enter the number of steps: \n"
message2: .asciiz "The factorial is: \n"
cont:     .asciiz "Do you want to continue? (Y or N) \n"
yes:      .byte 'Y'
no:       .byte 'N'
.text
main:

# $t1 contains the iterating number
addi $t1, $zero, 1

# $t3 contains the factorial
addi $t3, $zero, 1

# set $t2 which is the number we want a factorial for to 0
add $t2, $zero, $zero

# now $t5 contains 'Y' and $t6 contains 'N'
lb $t5, yes
lb $t6, no

while:
# show the message
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message
syscall

# read the number
li $v0, 5
syscall

# $t2 contains the condition for the loop, which is the number we want a factorial for
add  $t2, $t2, $v0

for:
    # while $t1 is less than $t2 do
    bgt  $t1, $t2, end
    # $t3 = $t3 * $t1
    mul  $t3, $t3, $t1
    # $t1++
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    # jump at the start of the loop
    j for

end:
    # prints "Do you want to continue?"
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, cont
    syscall

    # reads a character
    li $v0, 12
    syscall

    # if the answer is yes, jump to the start of the while loop
    beq $v0, $t5, while

    # if no, show the result
    beq $v0, $t6, show

    # else ask another time
    j end

show:
    # prints out the message
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, message2
    syscall
    # prints out the result
    li   $v0, 1
    add  $a0, $zero, $t3
    syscall

# end of the main function
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Usually by "character" is meant a single byte, and to be able to read binary input streams you need to read N bytes, "enter" has no meaning in that. Reading keyboard input from console is actually for many reasons treated similarly to reading a file, so you can read it char by char, "enter" is then just another char in input stream. To read more complex constructs, like multi-digit number, or string, the MIPS OS does already parsing for you, and it needs to know where the number/word ends, so it reads input stream char by char until "enter" is detected. Then it converts those chars into value.